The problem with rendering and capturing form data.. REACT
I'm having an issue. I created a form, and when I click the button to add, which is in the index.tsx file, it's not adding. However, when I try to render the dummyProductList, it works. Let me share the code with you to take a look. The problem is that the productList.map isn't being rendered.
// React
import { useContext, useState } from "react";

// Componentes
import { TitleModals } from "@src/components/TitleModals/TitleModas";
import BtnConfirmation from "@src/components/botoes/Confirmation/confirmation";
import BtnNegacao from "@src/components/botoes/Negacao/negacao";

// Contextos
import { CustomizeSystemContext } from "@src/context/CustomizeSystemContext";
import { ModalContext } from "@src/components/Modal/modal";

// Zustand
import { userProductsStore } from "@src/store/userProductsStore";

// Icones
import { VscTrash } from "react-icons/vsc";
import { MdOutlineModeEdit } from "react-icons/md";
import { AddProduct } from "@src/modal/createEncomenda";

export interface IProduct {
  id: string;
  nome: string;
  date: string;
  transportadora: string;
  codigo: string | number;
  link?: string;
}

export default function Products() {
  // Context Tradução
  const { language } = useContext(CustomizeSystemContext);
  //=> Modal
  const { open } = ModalContext();

  const {} = userProductsStore();

  const dummyProductList: IProduct[] = [
    {
      id: new Date().toJSON().toString(),
      nome: "Carrinho De Brinquedo",
      date: "19/12/2004",
      transportadora: "Correios",
      codigo: "XYZ123456789",
      link: "https://exemplo.com/rastreamento/XYZ123456789",
    },
  ];

  const [productList, setProductList] = useState(
    dummyProductList as IProduct[]
  );

  const addProduct = (data: IProduct) => {
    setProductList([...productList, data]);
  };

  const ProductList = () =>
    productList.map((product) => (
      <tr key={product.id} className="hover:bg-base-200 cursor-pointer">
        <td className="rounded-l-lg">
          <div className="flex justify-center">
            <span className="block max-w-[130px]">{`${product.nome}`}</span>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>{`${product.date}`}</td>
        <td>{`${product.transportadora}`}</td>
        <td>{`${product.codigo}`}</td>
        <td>
          <a
            href={product.link}
            target="_blank"
            className="btn btn-outline btn-accent">
            Rastrear
          </a>
        </td>
        <td className="rounded-r-lg">
          <div className="flex justify-center gap-2">
            <span className="pulse">
              <MdOutlineModeEdit className="h-5 w-5" />
            </span>

            <span className="pulse">
              <VscTrash className="h-5 w-5" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));

    console.log(productList);

  const produtosAdicionados = (
    <div className="w-auto grid gap-4">
      <TitleModals>{language.modal_orders_title}</TitleModals>

      <div
        className="overflow-auto"
        style={{ maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 300px)" }}>
        <table className="table text-center">
          {/* head */}
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>{language.modal_table_name}</th>
              <th>{language.modal_table_data}</th>
              <th>{language.modal_table_transport}</th>
              <th>{language.modal_table_code}</th>
              <th>{language.modal_table_link}</th>
              <th>{language.modal_table_acoes}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <ProductList />

            {/*showPage === PageEnum.list && <ProductList list={productList} />*/}
            {/*showPage === PageEnum.add && (
              <AddProduct
                onBackBtnClickHnd={showListPage}
                onSubmitClickHnd={addProduct}
              />
            )*/}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-center py-3">
        <BtnConfirmation
          name={language.create}
          funcao={() =>
            open(
              <AddProduct
                onBackBtnClickHnd={() => open(<Products />)}
                onSubmitClickHnd={addProduct}
              />
            )
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  return produtosAdicionados;
}

Other file
// React
import { useContext, useState } from "react";

// Componentes
import BtnConfirmation from "@src/components/botoes/Confirmation/confirmation";
import BtnNegacao from "@src/components/botoes/Negacao/negacao";
import { TitleModals } from "@src/components/TitleModals/TitleModas";
import { IProduct } from "@src/pages/content/chatOpen/menuVertical/components/products";

// Contextos
import { CustomizeSystemContext } from "@src/context/CustomizeSystemContext";
import { data } from "jquery";

type Props = {
  onBackBtnClickHnd: () => void;
  onSubmitClickHnd: (data: IProduct) => void;
};




export const AddProduct = (props: Props) => {
  // Context Tradução
  const { language } = useContext(CustomizeSystemContext);

  const [nome, setNome] = useState("");
  const [date, setDate] = useState("");
  const [transportadora, setTransportadora] = useState("");
  const [codigo, setCodigo] = useState("");

  const { onBackBtnClickHnd, onSubmitClickHnd } = props;

  const onSubmitBtnClickHnd = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data: IProduct = {
      id: new Date().toJSON.toString(),
      nome: nome,
      date: date,
      transportadora: transportadora,
      codigo: codigo,
      link: "",
    };
    onSubmitClickHnd(data);
    onBackBtnClickHnd();
    console.log(data)
    console.log(onSubmitClickHnd)
    console.log(onSubmitBtnClickHnd)
    console.log(onSubmitBtnClickHnd(data))
  };

  return (
    <form
      className="w-[600px] grid gap-4 overflow-auto pr-1"
      style={{ maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 70px)" }}
      onSubmit={onSubmitBtnClickHnd}>
      <TitleModals>{language.modal_orders_title}</TitleModals>

      <div className="form-control w-full">
        <label className="label">
          <span className="label-text">{language.modal_table_name}</span>
        </label>

        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder={language.modal_table_insert_name}
          className="input input-bordered w-full input-sm"
          value={nome}
          onChange={(e) => setNome(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-between gap-6">
        <div className="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
          <label className="label">
            <span className="label-text">{language.modal_table_data}</span>
          </label>

          <input
            type="Date"
            className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs input-sm"
            value={date}
            onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-control w-full max-w-xs">
          <label className="label">
            <span className="label-text">{language.modal_table_code}</span>
          </label>

          <input
            type="text"
            className="input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs input-sm"
            placeholder={language.modal_table_insert_code}
            value={codigo}
            onChange={(e) => setCodigo(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="form-control w-full">
        <label className="label">
          <span className="label-text">{language.modal_table_transport}</span>
        </label>

        <select
          className="!py-0 select select-bordered !select-sm w-full"
          onChange={(e) => setTransportadora(e.target.value)}>
          <option value={""}>{language.noneSelected}</option>
          <option value={"Correios"}>Correios</option>
          <option value={"Jadlog"}>Jadlog</option>
          <option value={"Outras"}>Outras</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div className="flex justify-center gap-2 items-center m-auto pt-4 resize-none">
        <BtnConfirmation name={language.added} funcao={onSubmitBtnClickHnd} />
        <BtnNegacao name={language.cancel} funcao={onBackBtnClickHnd} />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

I've tried everything, but it's not rendering.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Keep the button type as submit and remove the onClick function.
The button with type submit will call the onSubmit in the Form, when that button gets clicked.
<form
  className='w-[600px] grid gap-4 overflow-auto pr-1'
  style={{ maxHeight: 'calc(100vh - 70px)' }}
  onSubmit={(e)=>onSubmitBtnClickHnd(e)}
>
  <TitleModals>{language.modal_orders_title}</TitleModals>

  <div className='form-control w-full'>
    <label className='label'>
      <span className='label-text'>{language.modal_table_name}</span>
    </label>

    <input
      type='text'
      placeholder={language.modal_table_insert_name}
      className='input input-bordered w-full input-sm'
      value={nome}
      onChange={(e) => setNome(e.target.value)}
    />
  </div>

  <div className='flex justify-between gap-6'>
    <div className='form-control w-full max-w-xs'>
      <label className='label'>
        <span className='label-text'>{language.modal_table_data}</span>
      </label>

      <input
        type='Date'
        className='input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs input-sm'
        value={date}
        onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>

    <div className='form-control w-full max-w-xs'>
      <label className='label'>
        <span className='label-text'>{language.modal_table_code}</span>
      </label>

      <input
        type='text'
        className='input input-bordered w-full max-w-xs input-sm'
        placeholder={language.modal_table_insert_code}
        value={codigo}
        onChange={(e) => setCodigo(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className='form-control w-full'>
    <label className='label'>
      <span className='label-text'>{language.modal_table_transport}</span>
    </label>

    <select
      className='!py-0 select select-bordered !select-sm w-full'
      onChange={(e) => setTransportadora(e.target.value)}
    >
      <option value={''}>{language.noneSelected}</option>
      <option value={'Correios'}>Correios</option>
      <option value={'Jadlog'}>Jadlog</option>
      <option value={'Outras'}>Outras</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div className='flex justify-center gap-2 items-center m-auto pt-4 resize-none'>
    <BtnConfirmation
      type='submit'
      name={language.added}
      funcao={onSubmitBtnClickHnd}
    />
    <BtnNegacao
      type='button'
      name={language.cancel}
      funcao={onBackBtnClickHnd}
    />
  </div>
</form>;

